# orientdb unable to install on windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows, orientdb

I have followed the steps in the [url](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Windows-Service.html)  but I'm getting the following error when I run the installService.bat file. Please help me to get this db up and running.

> F:\orientdb-community-2.2.4\service>installService.bat C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Ja va\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
>   F:\sysnet\openempi\openempi-entity-3.1.0 The system cannot find the
>   path specified. Unable to create logger at ''

Answer (score 0):

does OrientDB 2.2.4 run successfully for you in its stand-alone server mode using server.bat?

Comment: This is the output I get when I run server.bat
F:\orientdb-community-2.2.4\bin>server                                                       
Invalid maximum direct memory size: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512g
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
F:\orientdb-community-2.2.4\bin>